# retrieve security groups using python boto but set vpc id

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, aws-sdk

i am trying to play around with python boto and i run the below example(below is the official doc for this).  I know for a fact that an SG called "Pub_HDP_SG" exist but when i try to run my command by passing in a parameter called groupnames i get below error.  I get the fact that this SG does not exist in my default VPC, so how do i set my VPC to a specific VPC ??

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html?highlight=get_all_security_groups#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.get_all_security_groups

```
>>> import boto
>>> ec2 = boto.connect_ec2()
>>> sg = ec2.get_all_security_groups()
>>> print sg
[SecurityGroup:default, SecurityGroup:Pub_HDP_SG, SecurityGroup:RDP Rule - open everyone , SecurityGroup:us-east-open-all, SecurityGroup:wordpress-app-SG, SecurityGroup:default, SecurityGroup:AWS-AMI-SG, SecurityGroup:launch-wizard-2]
>>>
>>> sgn = "Pub_HDP_SG"
>>>
>>> sg = ec2.get_all_security_groups(groupnames=[sgn])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/ec2/connection.py", line 2968, in get_all_security_groups
    [('item', SecurityGroup)], verb='POST')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/boto/connection.py", line 1186, in get_list
    raise self.ResponseError(response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>InvalidGroup.NotFound</Code><Message>The security group 'Pub_HDP_SG' does not exist in default VPC 'vpc-b3bf61d6'</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>c708a4cd-0bc9-4761-a5a6-556b1c68ecdb</RequestID></Response>
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quirky aspect of the EC2 API.  The `group names` parameter will only work with security groups in the default VPC (or EC2 Classic).  If you want to find groups in any VPC by name, use the `filters` parameter instead.

```
groups = ec2.get_all_security_groups(filters={'group-name': [sgn]})
```

This should return the list but note that it still returns a list of groups, not just the scalar group object.

Comment: okay that makes sense.  I did the below and was able to get what i am looking for...one additional question i have is, how do i know what filters i can use...looking at the doc's i do not see what filters that can be used                               >>> fts = { 'vpc_id':'vpc-1895327d', 'group-name': 'Pub_HDP_SG'}
>>> groups = ec2.get_all_security_groups(filters=fts)
>>> print groups
[SecurityGroup:Pub_HDP_SG]
>>>

Comment: There are two places I know of that have the docs for filters.  The first is the EC2 API docs (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSecurityGroups.html)  and the second is the docs for AWSCLI (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-security-groups.html).